# Initialize a 2D array with stack - Java

Tags: java

I would like to declare a 2D array and each coordinate [x][y] will return a Stack. 
So, I started with this

```
    private Stack<Balloon>[][] location;
```

and I try to create memory space for it. I tried this, but I failed

```
    location = new Stack<Balloon>()[width][height];
```

should I do something like

```
for(int i=0; i < width; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < height; j++){
        location[i][j] = new Stack<Balloon>();
    }
}
```

or there is a special way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, based on your description, maybe this might work out better?

```
Map<Point, Stack<Balloon>> map = new HashMap<Point, Stack<Balloon>>();
```

A `Point` has an x and a y coordinate already, and is part of the standard library.

that way, you can query a specific stack by using:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
Point point = new Point(x, y);
Stack<Balloon> balloons = map.get(point);
```

Comment: But when I try to input a Balloon, it seems quite annoying

Comment: If i want to insert a Balloon, i will have to to balloons.getPoint(point).push(balloon) ? Ahh looks fine

Comment: Maybe you could write `insert()` and `remove()` routines that do all that nasty syntax work behind the scenes :p

Answer (score 0):

```
location = new Stack[width][height]; // remove generic
```

Comment: This get a type safety warning

Comment: As I know in newer java versions this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
location = new Stack<Balloon>()[width][height]; // Invalid
location = new Stack<Balloon>[width][height]; // Valid!
```

You should then loop through if you don't want the values to be null.